# ¿Que pasa si accidentalmente bloqué el puerto 22 para las conexiones ssh de un instancia EC2?

Tags: aws, ec2, firewall

Estaba configuradno nginx y al parecer configure el firewall para que solo permitiera las conexiones http y https ahora intento conetarme de nuevo y no puedo me da un error de time out ¿Hay alguna manera de recupera la intancia?

Answer (score 1):

Si por firewall te refieres al grupo de seguridad es tan sencillo como editar dicho grupo y dar acceso por el puerto 22.

Si has modificado el firewall de la propia instancia, me temo que tendrás que eliminar dicha instancia y crear otra nueva. En la nueva instancia olvídate de restricciones vía software. AWS pone a tu disposición los grupos de seguridad precisamente para restringir el tráfico que entra y sale de la propia instancia.